# conexão com Base de dados

Tags: java, mysql, conexão

Olá, estou tendo um problema com o mysql_connector, pois, ele não está me retornando a string de conexão com a DB,mesmo eu já tendo incluído na classpath do Netbeans,e tendo feito outros scripts onde ele me trás a string de conexão. Nesse caso, como segue no código abaixo, fiz um try catch, com as variáveis de usuário ,senha e url, mas mesmo assim, ele não me retorna a string de conexão como normalmente deveria. Segue abaixo a classe de conexão e o script que funcionou,

Classe de conexão:

```java
package br.com.mySystem.dal;

import java.sql.*;


/**
 *
 * @author Daiana
 */
public class ModuloConexao {

    public static Connection conector(){
        java.sql.Connection conexao = null;

        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/project";
        String user ="root";
        String pass ="";

        try {
           Class.forName(driver);
           conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass );
           return conexao;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            return null;
        }


    }

}
```

Classe principal:

```java
package br.com.mySysttem.telas;
import java.sql.*;
import br.com.mySystem.dal.ModuloConexao;

/**
 *
 * @author Daiana
 */
public class TelaLogin extends javax.swing.JFrame {
 Connection conexao = null;
 PreparedStatement pst = null;
 ResultSet rs = null;

    /**
     * Creates new form TelaLogin
     */
    public TelaLogin() {
        initComponents();
        conexao = ModuloConexao.conector();
        System.out.println(conexao);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Publi-Systems");
        setResizable(false);

        jLabel1.setText("Usuario");

        jLabel2.setText("Senha");

        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btn.setText("Login");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(btn)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2))
                        .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1)
                            .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 208, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                .addContainerGap(77, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(btn)
                .addContainerGap(33, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaLogin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaLogin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaLogin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaLogin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TelaLogin().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btn;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
```

Script aleatório que funcionou:

```java
package mytest;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Daiana
 */
public class Mytest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String classNome = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        try{
       Class.forName(classNome);
            System.out.println("Driver carregado com sucesso");
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println("Driver falhou em carregar");
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No teste que funcionou, você não está abrindo a conexão, apenas carregando o driver. No script principal em que o erro está ocorrendo, podemos dizer que o driver está sendo carregado corretamente em `Class.forName (driver);` no entanto quando a conexão está realmente sendo feita em `connection = DriverManager.getConnection (url, user, pass);`uma exceção está sendo lançada, mas você está ignorando o erro e retornando `null`.

Primeiro, seria melhor colocar um `e.printStackTrace ()` antes de retornar `null` no try..catch do método conector, para que você possa ver claramente qual é o problema, que pode ser o que endereco `localhost:3308` está errado, ou o banco de dados `project` não existe ou a senha não pode ser vazia, ou simplesmente o banco está desligado.

Comment: Olá,desculpe um pouco a demora do feedback, mas eu tinha achado qual o problema. O que tava me jocgando para a exceção, era um bug estranho que o mysql tinha com o fuso horário,  por fim, apenas tinha que passar uma condicional dentro da string de conexão para estabelecer que o pacote de fuso-horários seja igual a UTC.

Comment: Foi realmente um bug estranho